# Update/Trim a value within a Lambda where expression 

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda, where-clause

I have a Lambda where expression which filters a list of customer based on a ID passed in. This works fine however I want to remove the timestamp from the CreationDate field when I return the records. Is there anyway to do this within the Lambda expression?

So this is my Lambda expression which returns my customer records:

```
customers = customers.Where(c => c.Business_Type == businessType);
```

However I'd like to do something like the following:

```
customers = customers.Where(c => c.Business_Type == businessType, c.CreationDate=c.CreationDate.Value.ToShortDateString());
```

Comment: To answer your question, yes you can. Turn the expression in a method like: customers = customers.Where(c => { bool r = c.Business_Type == businessType; c.CreationDate=c.CreationDate.Value.ToShortDateString(); return r}); not that it's recommended...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ is not meant to perform mutation of sequence elements. Just take the return value of `Where` and use `foreach` to perform the mutation, which is the idiomatic way to handle this:

```
var customers = customers.Where(c => c.Business_Type == businessType).ToArray();
foreach(var c in customers)
{
    c.CreationDate = c.CreationDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```